SwiftUI reference cycle, StateObject leaked
I've found this weird behavior and I cannot explain myself why is happening and how can I get rid of it.
Consider this code I tried to make a smaller MVP:
enum Sheet: Int, Identifiable {
    var id: Int {
        self.rawValue
    }
    
    case detail
    case tutorial
}

struct HostingView: View {
    
    @State var isPresenting: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Press to present") {
            isPresenting.toggle()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
            MyModelView()
        }
    }
}

struct MyModelView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @State private var presentedSheet: Sheet?
    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var messageList = [Message]()


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(messageList) { message in
                MessageView(with:message)
            }
            Button("Dismiss") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        .task {
            await model.loadData()
            self.messageList = buildMessages(with: model.data)
            
        }.sheet(item: $presentedSheet) { sheet in
            switch sheet {
            case .detail:
                Text("Detail")
            case .tutorial:
                Text("Tutorial")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func buildMessages(with data: [Int]) -> [Message] {
        [
            Message(text: "Interesting message \(data[0])"),
            Message(text: "Interesting message with action \(data[1])", buttonAction: {
                presentedSheet = .tutorial // HERE THE REF CYCLE
            })
        ]
    }
}


struct Message: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let text: String
    let buttonAction: (() -> Void)?
    
    init(text: String,
         buttonAction: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.text = text
        self.buttonAction = buttonAction
    }
}

struct MessageView: View {
    let text: String
    let buttonAction: (() -> Void)?
    
    init(with message: Message) {
        self.text = message.text
        self.buttonAction = message.buttonAction
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(text)
            if let buttonAction {
                Button(action: {
                    buttonAction()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Press Here")
                })
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
               alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color.red)

    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Int] = []
    
    func loadData() async {
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000)
        await MainActor.run {
            self.data = [1,2,3,4]
        }
    }
}

I have a view that is presented modally fullscreen, this view instantiate a StateObject, using a .task modifier once it appears it starts to download data asking to the model to fetch them.
After the model has download those info it builds some Message model that have to be displayed in the view.
Some of those messages have a callback for a button buttonAction, that pressed have to display a specific sheet. 
The callback is inject by directly accessing the @State variable presentedSheet to trigger the correct action.
This message array is then looped in a ForEach to build MessageView.
Looking at the memory graph I saw that the Model instance is not deallocates after dismissing the view. A@StateObject should be deallocated when the view that creates it disappear, but is not happening. The Model instance is retained by the Message buttonAction closure with presentedSheet = .tutorial and never released. if I comment that part of code I can see that the Model is dealloced correctly.
Since they are all structs I cannot weaken the reference, second why is happening should be self eventually passed by copy? How can I get rid of this ref cycle?

That's a really interesting case. It appears indeed that the closure is the culprit but since we're only referencing the struct we can only assume that this is bound to the whatever behind-the-scenes managed state SwiftUI holds for this view (that is after all how the framework can keep track state changes for structures). So short-story we can do nothing about it (in its current form). Here is a similar issue demonstrating the problem

As a sidenote. I understand that this is a minimal example but I would argue that it's not a very suitable one. For example, model doesn't even need to be a StateObject - it doesn't even have to be an ObservableObject for this case. It could just live inside the task for this code.

@Alladinian thank you for your comment. Of course the MVP is just for showing the issue that is part of a bigger app.

I the link you posted, you can easily weaken the model in the closure, but here I'm not using the model in the closure.
The ref cycle happens due to the Message instance in the @State property array that contains them.

Agreed. That why I said "similar". The gist of this is that whatever holding up a strong reference in your example is not directly controllable (unlike the one in the post I've linked).

The point of .task is to remove the need for @StateObject so you could try removing it

Currently you create a new model, @StateObject var model = Model() that has no relations to any other, every time you display the MyModelView().
Try this approach using a single source of truth for your data model, declared
in the HostingView and passed to other views using .environmentObject(model)
as shown in the example code:
 struct HostingView: View {
     @StateObject private var model = Model()  // <--- here
     @State private var isPresenting: Bool = false
     
     var body: some View {
         Button("Press to present") {
             isPresenting.toggle()
         }
         .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
             MyModelView()
                 .environmentObject(model) // <--- here
         }
     }
 }

 struct MyModelView: View {
     @EnvironmentObject var model: Model  // <--- here
 
     // .....
 

See also Monitoring data
it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.

Even if I create the Model instance in the presenting view doesn't fix the issue if the HostingView disappear the Model object is not deallocated. I do understand that you expect me to create the one instance at the beginning of the app, but I think that really depends on the use case.
This MVP is made to understand how even if we are working using struct there is a ref cycle in the @State var messages. and why even if it's on a View type, it brings the model with it (even if the View itself is not leaked).
